# jasmine(js) tests for a simple html/js page with full js functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I have an html/js(jquery) app that has the below functionality:

when a button is clicked, a modal opens and shows input details, we can enter and submit them. The submitted details will be stored in localstorage and automatically page gets rendered with new content.

Enter entry that we make appears as a row on the page.

Thats it !

I want to write tests for it.
So, what tests do I need to write for this app?

1. just test what each and every function returns.
2. test functionality of app. For example, add some sample entries and check whether they are displayed on the page as required.
3. Any others as you suggest.

By the way, is jasmine ok for this types of apps?

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine is great for these kind of apps and you might want to couple it with a test runner such as Karma JS.
In a sense you need to write:
1. Small and focused unit tests that mock as much of the functionality that is not tested such as server side calls. For this I use Karma/Jasmine/Sinon.
2. Functionality/UI/Integration test using an automation framework such as Casper JS driving PhantomJS to mimic actual user interactions.
3. Make sure you have good code coverage with Karma's code coverage plugin running Istanbul (included).